# Remove unnamed and the serial number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i cant seems to remove the unnamed and also the serial number from the csv file. i've look online it says using index_col = 0. but still not working.

Is there any other way doing it?

Code is :
 `brics = pd.read_csv('brics.csv', index_col = 0)`

and the csv output is :

```
 Unnamed: 0.1 country capital area population
0 BR Brazil Brasilia 8.516 200.40
1 RU Russia Moscow 17.100 143.50
3 CH China Beijing  9.597 1357.00
4 SA South_Africa Pretoria 1.221 52.98
```

What i need to to remove the unnamed:0.1 and also the serial number

Thanks

Thanks

[image]

Comment: check the answer posted and let us know if any works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use if you really want no index to be printed:

```
brics.drop(['Unnamed:0.1'],axis=1,inplace=True)
print (brics.to_string(index=False))
```

if you don't want  to loose the data in the unnamed column, simply rename it:

```
brics.rename(columns={'Unnamed:0.1':'something'},inplace = True)
```

if you want this to be your axis, add the below line after you rename the column:

```
brics.set_index('something')
```

post this you can call the print function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you call a "serial number" is the index of your dataframe (dataframe is your object type - pandas.DataFrame) so you cannot remove it.
Read more about removing the index in that SO Post:
[Removing index column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107570/removing-index-column-in-pandas)

to remove your unnamend column try:

```
brics = pd.read_csv('brics.csv', index_col = 0)  
brics =brics.drop(columns=['Unnamend: 0.1'])
brics
```