# AES encryption for csv file columns: Decryption is not working

Tags: pandas, csv, aes, python-3.7, pycrypto

I am trying to write an AES script that takes the name of a few columns and encrypts then and generates a new csv file with encrypted columns.

The script can also take a password and encrypted csv file to decrypt it.

The decryption part of the code isn't working.

I have tried playing around with encode and decode. And checking for logic errors.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
import os
import time
import getpass

'''
# AES 256 encryption/decryption using pycrypto library
Credits: https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/python/aes-256-encryption-and-decryption-in-python.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256

''' 
BLOCK_SIZE = 16


def get_private_key_salt(password, salt=None):
    if salt == None:
        salt = os.urandom(16)
    kdf = PBKDF2(password, salt, 64, 100000)
    key = kdf[:32]
    return [key,salt]


def encrypt(raw, private_key):
    iv = os.urandom(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(pad(raw.encode('utf-8'),BLOCK_SIZE)))


def decrypt(enc, private_key):
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:16]
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    #line56
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]),BLOCK_SIZE)


def encrypt_cols(encryption_dict,password):
    encrypted_dict = {}
    encrypted_dict['salt'] = []
    for dict_key in encryption_dict.keys():
        encrypted_dict[dict_key] = []
        for index in range(0,len(encryption_dict[dict_key])):
            try:
                key_salt_pair = get_private_key_salt(password,encrypted_dict['salt'][index])
            except IndexError:
                key_salt_pair = get_private_key_salt(password)
                encrypted_dict['salt'].append(key_salt_pair[1])
            cipher_text = encrypt(str(encryption_dict[dict_key][index]), key_salt_pair[0])
            encrypted_dict[dict_key].append(cipher_text.decode("utf-8"))

    return encrypted_dict


def decrypt_cols(encrypted_dict,password):
    decrypted_dict = {}
    decrypted_dict['salt'] = encrypted_dict['salt']
    for dict_key in encrypted_dict.keys():
        decrypted_dict[dict_key] = []
        if dict_key != 'salt':
            for index in range(0,len(encrypted_dict[dict_key])):
                key_salt_pair = get_private_key_salt(password,encrypted_dict['salt'][index])
                cipher_text = encrypted_dict[dict_key][index].encode('utf-8')
                #line88
                plain_text = decrypt(cipher_text, key_salt_pair[0]).decode('utf-8')
                decrypted_dict[dict_key].append(plain_text)
    return decrypted_dict


def prep_encryption_cols(encrypt_list):
    encryption_dict = {}
    for col_name in encrypt_list:
        try:
            encryption_dict[col_name]=df[col_name]
        except KeyError:
            print('No column with name \''+col_name+'\' Found. De-identification Failed!')
            sys.exit()
    return encryption_dict

def encryption(df, encrypt_list,password):
    encryption_dict = prep_encryption_cols(encrypt_list)
    encrypted_dict = encrypt_cols(encryption_dict,password)

    for key in encrypted_dict.keys():
        df[key] = encrypted_dict[key]

def decryption(df, decrypt_list, password):
    encrypted_dict = {}
    for col in decrypt_list:
        encrypted_dict[col] = df[col]
    encrypted_dict['salt'] = df['salt']
    decrypted_dict = decrypt_cols(encrypted_dict,password)
    del df['salt']
    for key in decrypted_dict.keys():
        if key != 'salt':
            df[key] = decrypted_dict[key]

password = getpass.getpass(prompt='Type Password Here:')

'''
ENCRYPTION
'''
start = time.time()

#read csv file
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
#convert it into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
encrypt_list = ['FIELD2', 'FIELD3']
del_list = ['FIELD4','FIELD5']
encryption(df, encrypt_list, password)

df.to_csv('encrypted_test.csv')

end = time.time()
print('It took '+str(end - start)+' seconds to encrypt')

'''
DECRYPTION
'''
start = time.time()

data = pd.read_csv('encrypted_test.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

decrypt_list = ['FIELD2', 'FIELD3']
decryption(df, decrypt_list, password)

df.to_csv('decrypted_test.csv')

end = time.time()
print('It took '+str(end - start)+' seconds to decrypt')
```

I get this error when I store the encrypted data in csv file and then read it for decryption

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\>python3 clean.py
It took 0.06599974632263184 seconds to encrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clean.py", line 167, in <module>
    decryption(df, decrypt_list, password)
  File "clean.py", line 128, in decryption
    decrypted_dict = decrypt_cols(encrypted_dict,password)
  File "clean.py", line 88, in decrypt_cols
    plain_text = decrypt(cipher_text, key_salt_pair[0]).decode('utf-8')
  File "clean.py", line 56, in decrypt
    return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc[16:]),BLOCK_SIZE)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\Crypto\Util\Padding.py", line 90, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

The program performs fine if I directly use the dataframe to perform decryption without storing it in csv file.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When encrypting, the salt is stored as *bytes* literal in the csv-file. When decrypting, the salt is interpreted as a *string* literal, which factually means that a different salt and thus a different key is used. The wrong decryption also leads to an invalid padding, which results in the error message *Padding is incorrect*.

The different salts during encryption and decryption can be easily checked with the debugger by comparing the value and type of `key_salt_pair[1]` in `encrypt_cols` and (the corresponding) `encrypted_dict['salt'][index]` in `decrypt_cols`.

The determination of the original salt is easiest if it is stored as a hexadecimal string, and can be implemented in `get_private_key_salt`:

```
def get_private_key_salt(password, salt=None):
    if salt == None:
        saltBin = os.urandom(16)
        salt = saltBin.hex()
    else:                             
        saltBin = bytes.fromhex(salt)    

    kdf = PBKDF2(password, saltBin, 64, 100000)
    key = kdf[:32]

    return [key,salt]
```

Alternatively, the change can also be made in `encrypt_cols` and `decrypt_cols`.

Another point is: In the current code, the csv-files still have the `DataFrame`-column. This can be removed by setting the index-parameter in `pandas#DataFrame#to_csv` to `False`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36572039/9014097).

Comment: It fixed the problem. Due to incorrect padding error, I was looking only into the ciphertext and did the debugging steps you suggested but only for the ciphertext. I also fixed the DataFrame-column. Thank you.

Comment: `salt = saltBin.hex()` needs indentation fix