# Pandas remove the row index from the pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe with the data as follows

```
  id  Name   Age     
0  1  XXX    30
```

and i have to remove the 0(the row index value) from the dataframe.

I have tried the folowing

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True) # Resets the index, makes factor a column
df.drop("Factor",axis=1,inplace=True)
```

but it is not removing the 0.

i want output like:

```
id  Name   Age     
 1  XXX    30
```

Comment: Do you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20107570) ?

Comment: Do you want to save csv file without index?

Comment: it is not possible to display something like that however you can take output into csv.

Comment: @jezrael i tried but it is not removing the index value.

Comment: @DishinHGoyani just i want the df with the 0 removed

Comment: dataframe without index can not exist. You can make id as index, by using set_index() function. While saving to file (csv etc), you can make index = False.

Comment: @MohitSharma i am not saving to csv.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pandas index is not a separate column that you can remove. It's an indicator like the indicator in array and dictionary.

For example if you have:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
letters[2]
```

2 is an indicator that cannot be removed from array.

But depending your use of dataframe you can tell pandas not to show index in the export.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas function `set_index`

```
df.set_index('id', inplace=True, drop=True)
```