# How to do Categorical in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy, if-statement

I have some table which is look like this :

[image: Cars Purchased Bike 0 0 No 1 1 No 2 2 No 3 1 Yes 4 0 Yes ... ... ... 995 2 Yes 996 0 Yes 997 0 Yes 998 3 No 999 2 Yes]

I would like to create two items 0 and 1 from the Cars column
0 = if you dont have car
1= for car owners, no matter how many
later, i Want to check if there is some relation between purchased bike and having car. How to do that ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas' `.loc()` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
df.loc[(df['Cars'] >= 1, 'Cars')]=1
print(df)
```

Comment: Hi, but i need just only two columns "Cars" and "PurchasedBike"    When I was trying select just only two. i got all dataframe. 
df[['Cars','Purchased Bike']]
df.loc[(df['Cars'] >= 1, 'Cars')]=1
print(df)

Comment: The column on the left, is the index column and can't be deleted. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107825/12602208)